# Grails nullable column returns value = {"class":"java.lang.Character"} in JSON

Tags: database, json, grails, char, legacy

I have a legacy database that I connect to and not sure why I get this result when I parse the json object in my client.  The column Character customersMname is defined in the domains static constraints as:

```
customersMname nullable: true, maxSize: 1
```

the result I get back from the JSON object when the field is null is:

```
<jsonname2>customersMname</jsonname2>
<jsonvalue2>{"class":"java.lang.Character"}</jsonvalue2>
```

There is actual data in the database column and it should be P.  Seems this is occurring with single character columns in MYSQL db when the datatype is defined as CHAR(1) or VARCHAR(1).  Any ideas?

Comment: What type is the property defined as in the domain class? Can you post your code that creates a JSON object?

Comment: The column is type Character, the domain class was auto generated by the db-reverse-engineer plugin in the STS ide.  Title of this should be changed to "Character column returns garbage".  I did fix this by changing the domain type to String but am curious if this is a bug or not?

Comment: In the future, you could add a custom JSON marshaller for your domain class (or even java.lang.Character to fix the issue in all cases) that generates the correct null value. That way you don't have to modify your generated domain class.

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that if they just fix Hibernate.  I will have to submit a bug fix for this.  But yes, that is a good idea to fix the current problems thanks Rhysyngsun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the system.  Work around is to change the domain type to String and be done with it.